# Please explain "java frame" meaning from stacktrace?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, bytecode, jit

In dump I see following information:

```
Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  com.barcap.fox.log.Syslog.plog(ILjava/lang/String;)Z+0
j  com.barcap.fox.log.Syslog.log(ILjava/lang/String;)Z+317
j  com.barcap.fox.log.Syslog$BS.flush()V+37
j  java.io.PrintStream.write([BII)V+30
....
```

Can you explain meaning of `Java frame`

I tryied to google it but I see only results related with swing(Jframe).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In other languages this would be called a "stack frame", but the Java Virtual Machine Specification uses just the term "frame". It is the segment of the call stack devoted to one invocation of a method, where that method keeps its state (local variables, parameters, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

A frame is essentially the space devoted to a function on a stack.

[image: Stack frame illustration]

Picture from [here.](http://people.eecs.ku.edu/~kpoduval/UMOD/stack_frame_x86.html)

The "Java frame" means that the frame is for Java code. There are these kinds of frames:

Native C frame (C), Interpreted Java frame (j), VM frame (V), VM generated stub frame (v), Other frame types, including compiled Java frames (J)

[See this.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/felog-138657.html)